# Python:circular import

Tags: python, web

I am trying to develop a localhost website but now I got this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_encode_idna' from partially initialized module 'werkzeug._internal' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: can you show output of `pip list`?

Comment: You have another file called **app.py**. There's no telling what is being called when you reach **app.run()**. but perhaps the run_simple is being imported at the **app.py** and this would cause a circular import.

Comment: You seem to have screwed up `sys.path` somehow. Python is looking inside your Flask install for top-level modules.

Comment: Actually, looking closer, you're writing your code **inside** your Flask install. Get out of there!

Answer (score 0):

You are writing code inside your Flask package. Move your code outside your environment.

You have created file `website.py` at the path `Lib/site-packagese/Flask/` which is wrong. Move your project outside of `Lib`. More appropriate place would be you home directory or desktop or any other place but not `Lib`.